How to Navigate an Excel Drop-down list with VBA?
I have a drop-down list with about 150 names, when I select a name from the dropdown, it gives me some information in another cell. I can navigate this drop-down menu myself with no issue, but I cannot figure out how to do it automatically.
If I want to pick a name manually, I select the cell, Alt + Up_Arrow, Down_Arrow, Enter
This moves me to the next name in the list. At this point I can automatically do the rest.
I tried the following code:
ws.Range("C3").Select ' This selects the cell with the drop-down
Application.SendKeys "%{UP}" ' (Alt + Up Arrow)
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Sadly this only opens up the dropdown list. I suspected that it was simply inputting the keypresses too fast, so I added a 1 second delay between each key press. This did not fix my issue.
It looks like entering the keypresses in this fashion does not work once the dropdown menu is open. Any ideas?
Side note: I have looked all over stackoverflow, reddit, various Excel tutorials on youtube, and I cannot find an answer. Additionally, I tried recording a macro where I moved down to the next entry in the drop-down. Sadly it produced no VBA code and did not do anything. I am quite new to using macros in Excel so be gentle.

I assume that by a "drop down" you mean a cell with data validation rules from a list?  If so, you can select the next item by comparing the current value of the cell with the list of all values and selecting the next one.
If data validation is populated by directly entered list of items:
Sub SelectNextValidationItem()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim validationList As Variant
    Dim currentValue As String
    Dim currentIndex As Integer
    Dim nextIndex As Integer
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    Set cell = ws.Range("C3") ' Change to your cell with data validation
    
    ' Get the list of validation items
    validationList = Split(cell.Validation.Formula1, ",")
    
    ' Get the current value of the cell
    currentValue = cell.Value
    
    ' Find the current index of the value in the validation list
    For currentIndex = LBound(validationList) To UBound(validationList)
        If validationList(currentIndex) = currentValue Then Exit For
    Next currentIndex
    
    ' Calculate the next index
    nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
    
    ' If the next index exceeds the list count, loop back to the first item
    If nextIndex > UBound(validationList) Then
        nextIndex = LBound(validationList)
    End If
    
    ' Set the cell to the next item
    cell.Value = validationList(nextIndex)
End Sub

And if the data validation uses a range of cells as its input:
Sub SelectNextValidationItemFromRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim validationRange As Range
    Dim validationList As Variant
    Dim currentValue As String
    Dim currentIndex As Integer
    Dim nextIndex As Integer
    Dim rangeAddress As String
    
    ' Set worksheet and cell
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    Set cell = ws.Range("C3") ' Change to your cell with data validation
    
    ' Ensure the cell has data validation of type list
    If cell.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
        ' Get the range of validation items
        rangeAddress = Mid(cell.Validation.Formula1, 2) ' Remove leading '='
        Set validationRange = ws.Range(rangeAddress)
        validationList = validationRange.Value
        
        ' Get the current value of the cell
        currentValue = cell.Value
        
        ' Find the current index of the value in the validation list
        For currentIndex = LBound(validationList, 1) To UBound(validationList, 1)
            If validationList(currentIndex, 1) = currentValue Then Exit For
        Next currentIndex
        
        ' Calculate the next index
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
        
        ' If the next index exceeds the list count, loop back to the first item
        If nextIndex > UBound(validationList, 1) Then
            nextIndex = LBound(validationList, 1)
        End If
        
        ' Set the cell to the next item
        cell.Value = validationList(nextIndex, 1)
    Else
        MsgBox "The selected cell does not have a data validation list.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub


If the validation list is derived from a row rather than a column, the validationList array will be a two-dimensional array with a single row and N elements.

@taller - good point but I didn't even consider it as for all practical purposes I don't row-based ranges are used for such purposes very often.
